# Split file into two files when pattern appears using command

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want a simple command (either AWK, Perl etc.) to split the file into two files as shown below.

`test.pem`:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I want to split this file into 2 files.

`filename.key` should contain the below content:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICdwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAmEwggJdAgEAAoGBALq6EmgljkwfHKkB
4s1BkXeYE/j0zO271m8IFerHyGVKjeq+RNJ/8vTNaeQSdpTfeGc5kTuNlK4vYFSS
8V2jVFwsXwKS63/H6sfzeFvgaFMJb/DghejxylajQ+71QXwsRdMmPJwH0JU3Yeju
hIA+NegFSU5BVbks8QZeGOeKQ0MlAgMBAAECgYBL6GynLe1FALjT89JRgsAyD/6+
jDXqxxuLE4xlX0YV91LuBN9Re3Y3EnJjpyXRq27097AUt5+jl9rfRsUcPdOC2s4W
txAEdJ2INgRbgilu2jgrKItPT9fC2e1oRJoHYIPHmE1SbXEqjm5fmelG7dqoNv95
Y/yr/YvIuF/aC8AEmQJBAOpYD0y5tr7wi0SXH2EWYlg4u+9++o14e+m0LDA8KbbL
uraS3XrHsS9IfKTLlJcyxTMQDA3TzYOfOAECs/hWlhcCQQDL+4Uz8yPVPkxoWFpH
qAauQ/kvxMQLRgJzc9+7EClAMbN3F26xl0GMmNE8eQ1A3622HG2ejMdgS07VOxOJ
rfIjAkEA3aACeDF63wFm9Ktnhc5Bm+Wr90hDdN/pcJBw6f08BiCOqHQk+iU5MNqA
5umR0Zy2WyBmBf21czF1KZ+AzPA2aQJAElEis/iIZjSy7cfJS5f2CZ4G+Vgk9pIx
1CY6l/Sqj54m7HHJOd9IPpTWbSS9oO61DZ5d5Zfkq2v3x0QHzBw3mwJBAKN1xO/3
RkwGrcgBUmviRpZN2GT6uNQd4lV1rLQXoPRqUUeFA7tSD198EXAiRGdMFMRBr+c6
C8ugBRjNMLUicy8=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

`filename.cert` should contain the below content:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using AWK:

```bsh
awk '/^-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----$/, /^-----END PRIVATE KEY-----$/ {print >"filename.key"; next} {print >"filename.cert"}' test.pem
```

Expanded AWK script:

```awk
/^-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----$/, /^-----END PRIVATE KEY-----$/ {
    print >"filename.key";
    next
}
{
    print >"filename.cert"
}
```

- If the current line is in the range of a `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and an `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----` line, prints the line to `filename.key` and skips to the next line; otherwise, prints the line to `filename.cert`.

```
% cat test.pem 
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
% awk '/^-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY------$/, /^-----END PRIVATE KEY------$/ {print >"filename.key"; next} {print >"filename.cert"}' test.pem
% cat filename.key 
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
% cat filename.cert 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: @sra1 You're welcome. If this and / or Byte Commander's answer helped you, remember to consider [accepting](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) one and, since you now have more than 15 reputation, also [upvoting](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) the answers that you found useful.

Comment: Can the awk command be more generic. Instead of searching for  -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- and an -----END PRIVATE KEY-----, search for -----BEGIN followed by some text with CERTIFICATE and -----END followed by same text with CERTIFICATE and then redirect to filename.cert and filename.key.                                                                                -----BEGIN <some label> CERTIFICATE-----                                                   -----END <some label> CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: @sra1 Just replacing `PRIVATE KEY` with `.* CERTIFICATE` should do

Answer (score 2):

You can also use two lines of `grep`:

```
grep -Pzo '(?s)-{5}BEGIN (PRIVATE KEY)-{5}.*?-{5}END \1-{5}' test.pem > filename.key
grep -Pzo '(?s)-{5}BEGIN (CERTIFICATE)-{5}.*?-{5}END \1-{5}' test.pem > filename.cert
```

The options `-P` enables Perl regexes, `-z` treats newline characters as normal characters and `-o` does only print the matching part, not the whole line (as `-z` causes the entire input to be treated as single line).

In the regular expression pattern, the switch `(?s)` causes that `.` also matches newline characters.
`-{5}BEGIN (PRIVATE KEY)-{5}` matches the block headline `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`.
`.*?` matches the block content (the key/certificate data).
`-{5}END \1-{5}` matches block end. The `\1` gets evaluated to the string in round brackets from above (`PRIVATE KEY` or `CERTIFICATE`).